# Does my Storyboard contain my views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am worried I am missing some high level understanding of Objective-C. Could someone clear this point up for me please?

When using storyboard I put ViewController on the design area. For example 'MyDetailViewController'. I then put labels, text boxes and such in this view controller.

Is this my view?

Am I being stupid and putting my controls within my controller instead of creating a separate view and connecting this to the controller or is the area I am working in within the storyboard essentially become my view and assigning a UiViewController class to the controller is correct?

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is both your view controller and its view. If you look closely you will see that they are two different things, and that they are connected by an outlet (the view controller's `view` outlet). This is the usual arrangement in a storyboard (a view physically inside its view controller in the canvas), though it is not absolutely required — if you wanted to, you could have this view controller get its view in some other way, e.g. from a *.xib* file.